# How to start activity with splashscreen in hidden mode

Tags: android, webview, screen, splash-screen

I have this application which starts displaying a splashscreen for 3 seconds then calls another activity to kick in which is a webview.

CODE SPLASHSCREEN

```
package test.test;

import test.test.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

int timer = 0;

@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

      Thread splashThread = new Thread() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
            try {
               while (timer < 3000) {
                  sleep(100);
                  timer += 100;            
               }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               // do nothing
            } finally {
               finish();
               Intent i = new Intent();
               i.setClassName("test.test","test.test.Mainmenu");
               startActivity(i);
            }
        }
      };
      splashThread.start();
   }
}
```

CODE XML SPLASH

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
    android:background="#57a11f" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

CODE WEBVIEW

```
package test.test;

import test.test.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Mainmenu extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 10 * 1024 * 1024 );
        webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/cache" );
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);     
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled( true );
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT );

        if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { 
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
        }

        webView.loadUrl( "http://www.google.com" );
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }   
}
```

CODE WEBVIEW XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#57a11f"
    tools:context=".Mainmenu" >

    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false" 
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

PROBLEM: when splashcreen calls the webview activity, it leaves me with a blank screen for a while, the time to download and render the page.

WHAT I WOULD LIKE: I'd like to know how can I start the splashscreen and the webview together at the same time but having the webview hidden so that it has 3 seconds to load and render the page in the background.

EXTRA: I am not looking for solutions using onPageFinished since i really want the splashscreen to stay on for 3 seconds and btw using onPageFinished doesn't avoid the render time needed to put the webpage on screen.

Thank you!

Comment: you can Use Asynctask to execute inside Mainmenu to Show Progress Dialogue untill Webview loads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ImageView and WebView in same layout file
And initially keeps webview in View.Gone Mode.

Once you spalsh screen finishes , enable the WebView View.Viasible and ImageView View.Gone

```
Pseudocode :

Webview=View.Gone;
ImageView=View.VISIBLE;
WebView.loadURL="<some url>";
SplasScreen timer for 3 seconds;
WebView=View.VISIBLE;
ImageVIew=View.GONE;
```

Use RelativeLayout or FrameLayout

Comment: thanks.. had to start from zero and needed some time since i am really at the beginning but manage to do as you said and works much better